# Blue border around text link cant get away on iOS device

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, iphone

I'm facing a problem on my iOS device. When opening the menu with popup, a blue border is around the text element. But its not a href hyperlink underline.

[image]

I tried following css code:

```
select:focus,
textarea:focus,
button:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

It dit nothing so I tried to disable the input outline for all

```
input {
 outline:none;
}
```

Unfortunaly it gives me no results. Please advise on how I can fix this problem.

Comment: can we have some more code please

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment above, more information/code would be helpful, however I have seen a similar issue recently and if the menu items are html links, try setting the outline to 0 on the < a > tag

```
a {
  outline: 0;
}
```

This appears to be the current iOS version of the old [dotted outline on html links](https://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline/)